# Error in Implementing Flink SQL Processing Time Temporal Left Join

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-sql, real-time-data, flink-table-api

I have a stream of data coming from Kafka which I want to enrich with a static data stored in Parquet files in Hadoop, and finally write to a Filesystem sink.

Initially I tried a lookup join as below,

```
SELECT t1.*,t2.enrichment_data_col from source_stream_table AS t1 
LEFT JOIN lookupTable FOR SYSTEM_TIME AS OF t1.proctime AS t2 
ON t1.lookup_type = t2.lookup_type
```

but got the below error

```
org.apache.flink.table.api.TableException: Processing-time temporal join is not supported yet.
    at org.apache.flink.table.planner.plan.nodes.exec.stream.StreamExecTemporalJoin.createJoinOperator(StreamExecTemporalJoin.java:292)
    at org.apache.flink.table.planner.plan.nodes.exec.stream.StreamExecTemporalJoin.getJoinOperator(StreamExecTemporalJoin.java:254)
    at org.apache.flink.table.planner.plan.nodes.exec.stream.StreamExecTemporalJoin.translateToPlanInternal(StreamExecTemporalJoin.java:179)
```

Next I tried to implement the Temporal Table Function LEFT JOIN as per
https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/dev/table/sql/queries/joins/#left-outer-join
as below,

```
TableDescriptor lookupDescriptor = TableDescriptor.forConnector("filesystem").format(FormatDescriptor.forFormat("parquet").build())
                .option("path",lookupFileLocation)
                .schema(Schema.newBuilder()
                        .column("lookup_type", DataTypes.STRING().notNull())
                        .column("enrichment_data_col",DataTypes.INT())
                        .columnByExpression("proc_time","PROCTIME()")
                        .primaryKey("lookup_type")
                        .build())
                .build();

tenv.createTable("lookupTable",lookupDescriptor);


TemporalTableFunction tmpLookup = tenv.from("lookupTable").createTemporalTableFunction($("proc_time"),$("lookup_type"));
tenv.createTemporarySystemFunction("lookupTableFunc",tmpLookup);


SELECT t1.*,t2.enrichment_data_col from source_stream_table AS t1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN LATERAL TABLE(lookupTableFunc(t1.proctime)) AS t2 
ON TRUE
```

but now getting the below error,

```
org.apache.flink.table.api.ValidationException: Only single column join key is supported. Found [I@6f8667bb in [Temporal Table Function]
    at org.apache.flink.table.planner.plan.utils.TemporalJoinUtil$.validateTemporalFunctionPrimaryKey(TemporalJoinUtil.scala:383)
    at org.apache.flink.table.planner.plan.utils.TemporalJoinUtil$.validateTemporalFunctionCondition(TemporalJoinUtil.scala:365)
```

The Temporal Table Function INNER JOIN syntax works fine though, but I am looking for a left join.

I tried it out with Flink Version `1.15.1` and `1.16.0`

Is there some other way to achieve Temporal LEFT JOIN in Flink or am I missing out something here.

Answer (score 0):

Your first attempt is [not supported indeed](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.16/docs/dev/table/sql/queries/joins/#processing-time-temporal-join):

> Currently, the FOR SYSTEM_TIME AS OF syntax used in temporal join with latest version of any view/table is not support yet

Basically, processing time is discouraged, being not deterministic. [You could try to com up with an event time](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.16/docs/dev/table/sql/create/#watermark):

```
order_time TIMESTAMP(3),
WATERMARK FOR order_time AS order_time - INTERVAL '5' SECOND
```

---

EDIT: remove second part (false information)

Comment: I did try the `ON t1.lookup_type = t2.lookup_type` initially in the second approach but got the below error:

`org.apache.flink.table.api.ValidationException: SQL validation failed. Left outer joins with a table function do not accept a predicate such as t1.lookup_type = t2.lookup_type. Only literal TRUE is accepted.`

Also as per the Flink official Doc, I can see only ON TRUE is supported
https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/dev/table/sql/queries/joins/#left-outer-join

Comment: Woops, indeed the doc says that. Edited the answer. The temporal joins are a bit of a mess. I did struggle with them a bit in the past; and sometimes your have to hack/try your way around it.
You could try to JIRA them: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-17397 
They are quite responsive and helpful if you come with reproducible bugs bundled as zip archives

Comment: I reported some of my issues. Maybe one fits yours:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-14297
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-14200
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-14173
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-20226
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-20105